# Calculate covariance of function of sample efficiently

Tags: estimation, covariance

Let $\phi(x, x')$ be a real-valued, continuous function that is symmetric with respect to exchange of its arguments. Let $X,X',X''$ be i.i.d random variables with distribution function $F$. I am interested in computing the two quantities
\begin{align}
\mu &= \mathrm{E}\phi(X,X')\\
\sigma^2 &= \mathrm{Cov}\left[\phi(X,X'),\phi(X,X'')\right].
\end{align}

If we can sample from $F$, we can easily compute $\mu$ and $\sigma$ by Monte Carlo integration: 
\begin{align}
\hat{\mu}&=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\phi(x_i,x'_i)\\
\hat{\sigma}^2&=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\left[\phi(x_i,x'_i)-\hat{\mu}\right]\left[\phi(x_i,x''_i)-\hat{\mu}\right],
\end{align}
where $x,x',x''$ are $n$ i.i.d. samples drawn from $F$.

However, I only have a single sample $x$ of $X$ and would like to compute the quantities above. My current approach is to use the following estimators
\begin{align}
\hat{\mu}&=\frac{1}{\binom n2}\sum_{i<j}\phi(x_i,x_j)\\
\hat{\sigma}^2&=\frac{1}{\binom n3}\sum_{i<j<k}\left[\phi(x_i,x_j)-\hat{\mu}\right]\left[\phi(x_i,x_k)-\hat{\mu}\right].
\end{align}

Unfortunately, I need to compute $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ a large number of times (inside a Metropolis-Hastings loop) and the combinatorial factor of $\binom n3$ is causing me a headache.

Do you have suggestions how to estimate the quantities I am concerned with more efficiently from a single sample?

Answer (score 1):

Factorise
$$
\sum_{j>i,k>i}\left[\phi(x_i,x_j)-\hat{\mu}\right]\left[\phi(x_i,x_k)-\hat{\mu}\right] \ =\ \left( \sum_{t>i}\left[\phi(x_i,x_t)-\hat{\mu}\right] \right)^2
$$

Or did you want $\sum_{k>j>i}\ldots$ ?  If so, same principle applies.  Let $A_{i,t}=\phi(x_i,x_t)-\hat{\mu}$, then:
$$
  \sum_{k>j>i}A_{i,j}A_{i,k}
\ =\ \frac{1}{2}\left( (\sum_{t>i}A_{i,t})^2 - \sum_{t>i} (A_{i,t})^2 \right)
$$

Comment: I did indeed mean $k>j>i$. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: It turns out the last expression should read $\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\left(\left[\sum_{j:j>i}A_{ij}\right]^2-\sum_{j:j>i}A_{ij}^2\right)$